# SQL grouping row by type and id

Tags: sql, database

I have a table logging date of issue equipment, like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable
    (`device_id` int, `datetime` datetime, `action` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO myTable
    (`device_id`, `datetime`, `action`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-08-01 11:00', 'out'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 11:05', 'out'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 11:10', 'out'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 11:15', 'out'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 11:20', 'out'),
    (2, '2015-08-01 11:25', 'out'),
    (3, '2015-08-01 11:22', 'out'),
    (4, '2015-08-01 11:45', 'out'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 12:00', 'in'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 12:01', 'in'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 12:02', 'in'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 12:03', 'in'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 12:04', 'in'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 12:05', 'in'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 12:10', 'out'),
    (2, '2015-08-01 12:12', 'in'),
    (3, '2015-08-01 12:12', 'in'),
    (3, '2015-08-01 12:22', 'out'),
    (4, '2015-08-01 12:23', 'in'),
    (1, '2015-08-01 08:00', 'in'),
    (3, '2015-08-01 09:12', 'in')
;
```

See example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9676/1/0)

How do I grouping the row of "out" and "in" device to one row? Like:

```
  datetime_out   |   datetime_in    | device_id |
-----------------+------------------+-----------+
2015-08-01 11:00 | 2015-08-01 12:05 |    1      |
2015-08-01 11:25 | 2015-08-01 12:12 |    2      |
2015-08-01 11:22 | 2015-08-01 12:12 |    3      |
2015-08-01 11:45 | 2015-08-01 12:23 |    4      |
2015-08-01 12:10 | 2015-09-03 08:00 |    1      |
2015-08-01 12:22 | 2015-09-03 09:12 |    3      |
```

**UPD:**

Any examples, the DBMS is not important.

If I have multiple "out" or "in" row with same device_id in sequence then selects row with max datetime for "in" and min datetime for "out", example:

```
   datetime      | device_id | action |
-----------------+-----------+--------+
2015-08-01 11:00 |     1     |  out   | <- Out 1 device
2015-08-01 11:05 |     1     |  out   | <- ignore
2015-08-01 11:10 |     1     |  out   | <- ignore
2015-08-01 11:15 |     1     |  out   | <- ignore
2015-08-01 11:20 |     1     |  out   | <- ignore
2015-08-01 11:25 |     2     |  out   |
2015-08-01 11:22 |     3     |  out   |
2015-08-01 11:45 |     4     |  out   |
2015-08-01 12:00 |     1     |  in    | <- ignore
2015-08-01 12:01 |     1     |  in    | <- ignore
2015-08-01 12:02 |     1     |  in    | <- ignore
2015-08-01 12:03 |     1     |  in    | <- ignore
2015-08-01 12:04 |     1     |  in    | <- ignore
2015-08-01 12:05 |     1     |  in    | <- In 1 device
2015-08-01 12:10 |     1     |  out   | <- Out 1 device
2015-08-01 12:12 |     2     |  in    |
2015-08-01 12:12 |     3     |  in    |
2015-08-01 12:22 |     3     |  out   |
2015-08-01 12:23 |     4     |  in    |
2015-08-03 08:00 |     1     |  in    | <- In 1 device
2015-08-03 09:12 |     3     |  in    |
```

Comment: How do you know the rows match?  What if there are multiple in's before an out or vice versa?

Comment: I could guess that for each out, you want the next in sequentially by datetime, but you really should clarify that in your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I would use cursors to achieve this. If you do not have too many rows and don't need instant results it can be fine. If not I would fill a table with the results periodically or keep a "Last Updated Date" somewhere to update the table with the new information only.

See example here : http://rextester.com/JRW52552

Here is what it could look like :

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (
    device_id INT,
    datetime_out DATETIME,
    datetime_in DATETIME
)

DECLARE device_cursor CURSOR FOR   
    SELECT DISTINCT device_id  
    FROM myTable

DECLARE @device_id INT
OPEN device_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM device_cursor INTO @device_id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DeviceLastInDatetime DATETIME = '1901-01-01'

    WHILE 1=1 --infinit loop to go through all out/in combinations
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @FirstOut DATETIME --find first out time after @DeviceLastInDatetime
        SELECT @FirstOut = MIN(datetime) 
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE device_id = @device_id AND action = 'out' AND datetime > @DeviceLastInDatetime
        PRINT '@FirstOut ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FirstOut) --DEBUG

        IF @FirstOut IS NULL --if no further out found, break infinit loop
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END

        DECLARE @NextIn DATETIME --Find @NextIn --to go pass all next out datetime
        SELECT @NextIn = MIN(datetime) 
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE device_id = @device_id AND action = 'in' AND datetime > @FirstOut
        PRINT '@NextIn ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @NextIn) --DEBUG

        DECLARE @NextOutAfterNextIn DATETIME --Find @NextOutAfterNextIn --to go pass all next in datetime
        SELECT @NextOutAfterNextIn = ISNULL(MIN(datetime) , '2099-01-01')
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE device_id = @device_id AND action = 'out' AND datetime > @NextIn
        PRINT '@NextOutAfterNextIn ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @NextOutAfterNextIn) --DEBUG

        DECLARE @FinalInDate DATETIME --last first 'in' before @NextOutAfterNextIn
        SELECT @FinalInDate = MAX(datetime) 
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE device_id = @device_id AND action = 'in' AND datetime < @NextOutAfterNextIn
        PRINT '@FinalInDate ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FinalInDate) --DEBUG

        INSERT INTO #Results VALUES (@device_id, @FirstOut, @FinalInDate)

        SET @DeviceLastInDatetime = ISNULL(@FinalInDate, '2099-01-01')
    END 


    --fetch next device
    FETCH NEXT FROM device_cursor INTO @device_id
END --device_cursor


CLOSE device_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE device_cursor;

SELECT * 
FROM #Results
ORDER BY device_id, datetime_out

DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: So you would like to have only one row per device? In that case your output example would not be correct, am I right?

Comment: Not quite, each device can be issued and to take any number of times.
Your query example works almost as it should,
but "in" row must be last in sequence, selected last "out" before the next issued ("in") row.
And the next "out" row before "in" row should not be displayed. In the example shown it right.

Comment: The answer has been updated according to your comments.

Comment: It really can be solved only in this way by procedure? I'd love to see a solution using only SQL query.

Comment: That's an Sql query, you don't need to execute it as a procedure.